# Why encrypted text is not decrypt in react native iOS app after when I generate archive?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am using react-native-crypto-js for encrypt and decrypt text message. But it is not working after release archive generated for iOS.

All things working fine in debug mode.

Here is code:

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(itemtwo.message.toString(), "xxxxxxxxxxx").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

it shows me blank message or stuck the app in release build. but all things working fine in Debug mode.

Comment: did you tried with try/catch and an alert to see if any error returns?

Comment: No I did not used try and catch because it is working fine in debug but in release it is not working.

Comment: but if you do put the code on a try/catch, with an alert, then generate the release apk, then try running your app, if the code doesn't run, it will show you an alert, of why, and then you can provide the error message. If there's not an alert, there's no error with your code above.

Comment: Ok I will try it and tell you the result.

Comment: Ok I got malformed utf-8 erro in catch

Comment: Any solutions because this works in debug mode no error in debug.but in release I got malformed utf-8 error